# airflow celery Jobs are stuck in running state

Tags: postgresql, rabbitmq, celery, airflow

I am trying to setup Airflow with `CeleryExecutor`. I am using `postgres` as database, `rabbitmq` as message broker.  All the airflow scheduled jobs are going to running state but they never run. I don't see any error in `rabbitmq` logs or airflow logs. any help is appreciated

Here is my broker and backend urls

```
broker_url = amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/airflow

celery_result_backend = db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@127.0.0.1:5432/airflow

sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@127.0.0.1:5432/airflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the Celery workers joined rabbitmq properly? You can consider to use flower for that, a web based tool for monitoring and administrating Celery clusters. You can simply run it using `airflow flower`

Most of the time, based on my past experience, when a task is scheduled but not running there is a problem with the Celery Workers. In our case, we use Postgres + Redis, and the was a connectivity issue between the workers and Redis.